# Migrating Archetype news items to Dexterity content types

Tags: plone, dexterity, archetypes

I'm trying to copy the content in news items to other content type that I wrote. In my script I have the `news` item and the `project` item. The second, `project`, is a content type defined using Dexterity. It would be wonderful if I could to copy the image and the body text from `news` to `project` in the next way.

```python
project.text = news.text
project.image = news.image
```

Where text and image are defined in the `project` schema as RichText and NamedBlobImage. I don't know how the attributes are in the news item. I only know that I can get the image in the news item using the method `getImage()` but assign it to the project generates an error when rendering the project.

So I need some pointers to solve my basic questions:

1. How can I know the attribute names for Archetype content types. For example, in this case I need to know the name of the attribute for the body text of news item.
2. How can I convert an image attached to a news item to an image attached to a dexterity content type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You use the field from the Archetypes schema to retrieve values, preferably the raw values in this case. You pass in the object then calling either `.get()` or `.getRaw()`:

   ```
   schema = news.Schema()
   news = schema.getField('text').getRaw(news)
   imageField = schema.getField('image')
   image = imageField.getRaw(news)
   content_type = imageField.getContentType(news)
   filename = imageField.getFilename(news)
   ```
2. The object returned by the `ImageField.getRaw()` call is basically a `OFS.Image` instance. You can call `str()` on it to get the raw image data.

   To *set* the image object, you really want to get the image field from the schema and use it's `._type` attribute as a factory:

   ```
   project.image = IProjectInterface.image._type(str(image),
       contentType=content_type, filename=filename)
   ```

   The content type here is optional; the `NamedImage` and `NamedBlobImage` types sniff out the content type automatically too.

Comment: Dank je vel, Martijn!